# JavaFX FXML RadioButton binding

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

How to bind a radio button to a model class?

```
    <fx:define>
    <ToggleGroup  fx:id="xxx" />
    </fx:define>    
    <children>
    <RadioButton text="one" toggleGroup="$xxx" fx:id="f1"/>
    <RadioButton text="two" toggleGroup="$xxx" fx:id="f2"/>
    </children>
```

`
model:

```
    private final StringProperty yyy = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "yyy", "");
```

with getters and setters

i tried something like this in controller

```
    @FXML
    private String yyy = "";
    @FXML private RadioButton f1;
    @FXML private RadioButton f2;
```

and then I can get the

```
    if (f1.isSelected()) 
    {yyy = f1.getText();}
```

and store the value of radio in String yyy, but how to send it to model from there..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand where you want to send what from where to where, but may be you can (bidirectionally? Unidirectionally?) bind `yyy` to `RadioButton.textProperty()`? Or maybe just use the `RadioButton.setText(String)` method.

Have a look at here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textProperty--

-- UPDATE after OP's comment --

What about having an object of class Model as a field in your controller? Something like:

```
class Model {
    private StringProperty yyy; // with getters and setters
}

class Controller {
    private Model model;
    [...]
    private void onButtonClicked() {
        if (f1.isSelected()) {
            model.setYyy(f1.getText())
        }
     }
}
```

If you have to share the same model object between different controllers, through the FXMLLoader you can access the controller of a view (with method `FXMLLoader.getController()` (after you have called `FXMLLoader.load()`) and call the `setModel(Model)` method to set the new controller's model

Comment: hah, yeah maybe my question is kinda chaotic when I read it now..
I have a form with text fields and radio buttons on view and a model that will accept the string values at button click..
I know how to connect bidirectionally the text field values but have problem with the logic for the radio buttons

Comment: I edited the answer as the code in comments is really ugly